# using variable with oracle database connection string

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g

I had small c# software that works on several database on several servers and I need to switch between different schema so..
depending on the current server ip I connect to master table on specified server 
and get the schema name then add as variable within the connection string by this way .. 
is it safe to use this way to make connection string flexible ?
if no then what do you suggest

```
string oradb = "Data Source=source;User Id=" + DBSchema + ";Password=pwd;";
```

Comment: this is totally doable I do it currently when switching between 2 different Oracle databases.. you will need 2 connection strings in your .Config file and in the connection string you will need to do something like this 
`string.Format("Data Source = {0};User ID = {1}; Password={2}"` etc...

Comment: I have lay'd out a step by step on how you could do this  this works like a charm and if you understand what I am doing in the `public string UserConnName
{` part of code you can see how it's possible to dynamically call a stored procedure this is one example to help get you started..

Answer (score 0):

In general run-time parameters are to be stored outside your code and in many cases the config file is one of the best places for that. You could use a factory method to build the connection string as in [CodeProject-Don't Hard Code Your Data Providers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55890/Don-t-hard-code-your-DataProviders) or you could write a few lines of code to set the values using the .NET connection string builder as in [ConnectionStringBuilder Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254947(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

for example currently I have a web application that 2 web forms that need 2 different connection I will show you how I have it for 1 of the 2 forms

```
public static string storedProcName = "NameOfSomeStoredProc";
public string ConnString
{
    get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConn2"].ConnectionString; }
}

public string UserConnName
{
    get { return string.Concat(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userConnName"], storedProcName); }

}
```

the method actual stored procedure call inside a method will look like the following I am passing in the Stored Proc name based on a static storedProcName declared above..

Create yourself a Helper Class and you can have something like the following that you would call from within your Class where you are wanting to execute the code

> HelperClass.cs

```
public static DataSet ExecuteDataSet2(string sql, CommandType cmdType, params OracleParameter[] parameters)
{
    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
    using (OracleConnection connStr = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConn2"].ConnectionString))
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, connStr))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 60 * 22;
        foreach (var item in parameters)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(item);
        }

        try
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            new OracleDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            utilities.SendErrorEmails(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
        return ds;
    }
}
```

> Your Web.Config for example would look like this if you have 2 different DB connection string.. you would create the same method as above calling it `ExecuteDataSet1....` and change the `DbConn2` to `DbConn` and in the Public string ConnString change the DbConn2 to DbConn in your other class or have a check box and depending on the selection you can store botn ConnString get retrun .. calling your other one ConnString2 pretty straight forward

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DbConn" connectionString="Data Source={0};User Id={1};Password={2};" />
    <add name="DbConn2" connectionString="Data Source={0};User Id={1};Password={2};" />
 </connectionStrings>

<appSettings>
    <add key="userConnName" value="NameOfOracleUser." />
</appSettings>
```

//Pay close attention to the `.` in the NameOfOracleUser., this depending how you have your procedures setup you would have OracleDbUserName.StoredProcedure name to execute.. notice in the `Populate_DataGrin` method I am passing the UserConnName and the string.Concat will pick up the storedProcName from this 
`public static string storedProcName = "NameOfSomeStoredProc";` works like a charm and if you had a dropdown of stored proc names to run.. it would work the same by assigning the name based on the drowpdown selection text..

last but not least the method / event that calls the ExecuteDataSet2 would look like this

```
private void Populate_DataGrin(int intMonth, string strLocation)
{
    dtSomeDataTable = OracleDBHelper.ExecuteDataSet2(UserConnName, CommandType.StoredProcedure
               , new OracleParameter("var_IntMonth", intMonth)
               , new OracleParameter("var_StrLocation", strLocation)
               , new OracleParameter
               {
                   ParameterName = "p_cursor"
                 ,
                   OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor
                 ,
                   Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
               }
             ).Tables[0];

    YourDataGrid.DataSource = null;
    YourDataGrid.DataSource = dtSomeDataTable;
    YourDataGrid.DataBind();
}
```